# помогите сделал вроде бы всё правильно но фонарик всё равно не включается /выключается скажите в чём мой косяк

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: вот скрин]

Я хотел чтобы мой фонарик вкл/выкл на клавишу f.

Вроде бы, я сделал всё как нужно, но ничего не происходит: он не включается и не выключается.

Подскажите в чём проблема и как её исправить?

вот  код

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Fonarik : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Light myLight;

    void Start()
    {
        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в таком виде на ваш вопрос ответить невозможно. Добавьте код и опишите что именно вы используете для реализации

Comment: выложите текст кода, а не картинку!

Comment: а myLight.enabled = true?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает. Проблема в названии файла скрипта. Оно должно совпадать с названием класса. С учетом реестра.
У вас класс называется Fonarik, а файл fonarik.  Переименуйте файл в Fonarik, и все заработает. Ещё советую прикрепить окно console среди основных экранов - там бы вы увидели подсказку.

Comment: я сделал как вы сказали но к сожалению у меня не чего не работает

Comment: Я проверял ваш код на сцене. Он работал. Попробуйте удались с объекта скрипт и заново его прикрепить. Если не поможет, пришлите еще раз скриншот, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ура заработало спасибо вам большое Александр .

Comment: Рад был помочь, Илья. Отметьте тогда ответ как правильный.